# Как правильно закешировать динамически обновляемый контент в WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ajax, кэширование

У меня сайт на **WordPress** с установленным плагином кеширования и включенным браузерным кэшем.

На главной странице есть блок `<div id="wrapper"></div>`, который должен динамически обновляться, поэтому я вывожу его посредством **ajax**, чтобы он не попал в браузерный кэш плагина.

Однако, периодичность динамического обновления контента составляет раз в неделю (каждую субботу) и рамках ускоренной загрузки и оптимизации сайта, я планирую добавить этот запрос в собственный динамический кэш, который будет сбрасываться раз в неделю в момент подтягивания нового контента.

Верно ли я понимаю, что, как только истечет срок кеширования *в заголовках Expires*, сможет отработать условие `if ( false === ( $buffer = get_transient( 'json_data' ) ) ) {..}` внутри функции **get_data()**?

Или кэш сбросится и затем сразу перезапишется, а условие так ни разу не отработает и контент будет всегда сохраняться устаревшим? Не хотелось бы рисковать, чтобы неверный контент закешировался в пользовательском браузере и его уже было бы нельзя очистить программными методами.

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
  wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'myajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function get_data() {

  $saturday = strtotime("next saturday");

  header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $saturday) . ' GMT' );
  header( 'Cache-control: public' );

  if ( false === ( $buffer = get_transient( 'json_data' ) ) ) {
    set_transient( 'json_data', $buffer, $saturday); 
  }

  echo $buffer;
  wp_die();
}

if( wp_doing_ajax() ){
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_front_slider', 'get_front_slider' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_front_slider', 'get_front_slider' );
}
```

**js**

```
(function($){   
    var data = { action: 'get_data' };

    $.post( myajax.url, data, function(response) {
        $('#wrapper').html(response);
    });
    
})(jQuery);
```

**P.S.** В объектном кэше `json_data` хранится запрос с API сервера, который тоже должен обновляться каждую неделю (раз в субботу)

Comment: Да, все верно

Но в Вашем примере кэшируется заголовки, но не $buffer. Используйте ob_start()/ob_get_clean() для вывода и получения буфферных данных

Comment: @4efirrr никаких ob_ функций тут не нужно, данные из transient читаются правильно. Тут много других ошибок, в то же время.

Comment: Время жизни браузерного кеша к времени жизни транзинта отношения не имеет. Кроме того, в set_transient устанавливается количество cекунд, которое будет храниться транзинт. Вы же туда пишете время, равное следующей субботе, т.е. кол-во секунд между January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC и началом следующей субботы. Это транзинт, который сбросится через 53 года от текущего момента.

Comment: Кроме того, вы через set_transient всегда сохраняет false. Вам перед set_ надо получить значение буфера через API сервера.

Comment: @KAGG Design спасибо, что обратили на это внимание! А как правильно тогда сохранить время жизни кеша в моём случае?

Comment: @KAGG Design так ведь я получаю значение буфера в этой строке с условием `if ( false === ( $buffer = get_transient( 'json_data' ) ) ) {..}`. get_transient возвращает false в случае пустого значения, так в кодексе описано и такого рода конструкцию не я придумал, к примеру, Миша Рудастых пользуется (а он точно авторитет в wordpress среде) https://misha.agency/wordpress/get_transient.html

Comment: вот так: `$now = time(); $saturday = strtotime("next saturday");$diff = $saturday - $now;`

Comment: Этот if срабатывает только если get_transient возвращает false. Т.е. транзинта нет. И у Миши там стоит сначала получение кешируемого значения через WP_Query, а уж потом transient. А вы выкинули из его кода самое главное.

Comment: @KAGG Design ааа, теперь понял! Да, вы правы, я не указал троеточие в том смысле, что в условии гораздо больше строк и там имеется конечно цикл получения значения буфера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи @KAGG Design пришёл вот к такому решению

**php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
  wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'myajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function get_data() {
  $now = time();
  $saturday = strtotime("next saturday");
  $diff = $saturday - $now;

  header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $saturday) . ' GMT' );
  header( 'Cache-control: public' );

  if ( false === ( $buffer = get_transient( 'json_data' ) ) ) {

    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    foreach($query->posts as $post) {
       ob_start();
       ...
       $buffer .= ob_get_clean(); 
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    set_transient( 'json_data', $buffer, $diff); 
  }

  echo $buffer;
  wp_die();
}

if( wp_doing_ajax() ){
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_front_slider', 'get_front_slider' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_front_slider', 'get_front_slider' );
}
```

**js**

```
(function($){   
    var data = { action: 'get_data' };

    $.post( myajax.url, data, function(response) {
        $('#wrapper').html(response);
    });
    
})(jQuery);
```